# Looking for a template engine which can be used in Java and JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, template-engine, google-closure

As the title says, I'm currently looking for a template engine that works with Java and Javascript. The idea is that my ajax json objects can use the same template files to render stuff client-side like Java is doing it server-side.

I know there is google-closure-template but it is working with guice 2.0 and my current project runs under guice 3.0 and both together just create wierd errors and I tried using them but failed for about 2 weeks now...

So is there anything apart from google-closure?

Comment: Just to notice: Google released a new version of closure template library which is now based on guice 3. So my problem vanished ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

Comment: This really looks interesting! Thank you.

Comment: I really had some quick working examples running. Really like it. I'm think I', going to use it for now. Really looking forward to Mustache 2.0 as it has precompiling for javascript - as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Also [Histone](http://weblab.megafon.ru/histone/en/) seems to be for both

BTW: the same topic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871425/cross-java-and-javascript-template-language)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but have you considered firing up a [`javax.script.ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) and running the same JS templating system in Java as well? That way you can choose the template system you actually want rather than compromising based on what languages implement it. I doubt that embedded JS in Java (Rhino/Nashorn) will perform as a well as a native Java implementation, but depending on your application that might not matter.