# Cross Java and Javascript Template Language?

Tags: java, javascript, template-engine

There seem to be a lot of template languages for both Java (e.g. JSP, JSTL, Freemarker, Velocity, ...) and for Javascript (e.g. Mustache, Ext's XTemplate, Jquery templates, ...) but is there one which have an implementation for both?

Ideally I'd like to be able to have an template which can be evaluated either on the server or on  the client side without too much  hassle switching over.

Comment: I would imagine no since they are 2 different languages

Comment: Mustache has implementations for both.

Comment: @GreenDay A templating language is syntax, which may be implemented in any language. Not having multiple implementations isn't a function of the language(s) used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Closure/Soy templates](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/).

The [Wikipedia Page for Web Templating Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) reveals another one: [Casper](http://code.google.com/p/casper/).

Both these solutions don't use a common template file which is directly evaluated in JS or Java. The template must first be compiled into an intermediate JS before evaluation on the client. (For Closure, this is fairly easy to do with `ant` and an included `SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar` command line tool. Not sure about with Casper.)

EDIT: Another possibility is [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), which does *not* require templates to be compiled.

Comment: Cheers for that. Yes I could have found this using Google eventually but can't you find most things using Google!?  I guess I'll know where to look from now on!