# Templates compiled to javascript in a Java environment

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, sails.js

Coming from **Node.js** and now working with **Java** I'm wondering about how to achieve with Java what I did with Node.js, more specifically: How to compile my templates into JS functions.

What I did before was using EJS templates, then they were compiled into a single JS file that exposed functions to call from JS with parameters, these functions returned a HTML string that I could use as it to update my view.

The great thing about this is that I could write my templates in separated files, (EJS) then dynamically Grunt/EJS (I guess, that's from Sails.js internal logic) was converting the template into a function, merged all of them and finally generating a single file usable in my app, I just had to call a function, provide arguments and that's it: I get a view dynamically generated.

I want to achieve the same in a Java environment, using Ant, maybe maven, but I don't know how to do it neither where to look for since I'm a Java novice.

Edit:

I'm talking about client-side templating, I just want to avoid the -ugly-traditionnal way to write HTML code inside JS strings and split them in separated files so I can maintain them easier. I only need to use them from JS, not from Java, but I need to "compile" them from a Java environment, using Ant.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking about Java metaprogramming by creating templates that compile into Java files as part of a build, or if you're asking about web view templates compatible with Java.  For the latter, have a look at JSP (Java Server Pages), [String Template](http://www.stringtemplate.org) or [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).  You may also be able to use it for metaprogramming, but there may be more specialized tools for that.  This question is rather broad and opinion-based, however...

Comment: @EricHughes I think he's talking about client-side template systems that translate templates into JavaScript functions (like [doT](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) or EJS in this case).  I think the answer is that some custom code is necessary; I've got a set of my own Ant tasks to do it.

Comment: Exactly @EricHughes, I'm talking about client side templating. Could you please guide me, if you have any resource or tutorial?

Comment: [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-ant-to-build-a-javascript-library--net-27014) is a couple years out of date but seems to what you're aiming for.  But, if Node.js/Grunt/EJS was doing everything you wanted, are you prohibited from calling Grunt from Ant for the specific tasks you want?

Comment: I can't use a Node.js environment to my chagrin, I have to use Java/Ant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085741/looking-for-a-template-engine-which-can-be-used-in-java-and-javascript), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871425/cross-java-and-javascript-template-language), so you may have a look there to see if there are other useful answers.

A consensus seems to be that [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), which has a Java-implemented compiler (among other flavors) could be executed as an Ant target.  It's a logic-less template, so you may want to find another solution.

Because it is possible to call Node.js scripts from Ant, it seems like an artificial restriction to not have Node.js.  You will have much more choice and flexibility in template choice if you can persuade your team to allow Node.js.

Node.js is not in an either-or relationship with Java tools.  There is plenty of room for both on a project, and I've worked on C# projects that use Node.js, just as I've worked on projects that use JRuby, Java, and Rails.  None of those technologies excludes the others.

Note that I'm *not* recommending that you try to persuade people to switch to Node.js as an environment, migrate existing code, or use Grunt, but if it's a useful tool that you're familiar with, I can't think of a single good reason why you should be denied its use.

Comment: I completely agree with you, the Node.js limitation is due do a human factor, they basically don't want to have to know another language/environment because it costs money, mostly, and also complicates the configuration and use if it needs to be installed in production.

Comment: In response to your coworkers, I'd say: if you're using client-side Javascript already, it's not a new language, just a new usage of a familiar one.  If you're only using Node.js and something to compile templates, it should be a minimal-enough part of your lives that it's not a big deal.  But, it will also give you access to such wonderful savers-of-time-and-money as JSHint and node-unit or unitjs or other such useful tools to ease maintainability of your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use this library I discovered yesterday. I've tried it and it seems to work well, some features are also quite useful for development mode, like the watcher on the templates.

http://jcruncher.org/

I think I'll go with it, just wondering about the author and his implication, and hope to see a Handlebars 3.0.0 compatible version soon, as well as the source code on GitHub.

P.S: You can find the handlebars compiler on the CDN (select the 2.0.0 version):

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/handlebars.js/
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.runtime.min.js